# How can I get prName and prQty from the double array?

Tags: html, vue.js

How can I get `prName` and `prQty` inside the 2D array?

```
html
<h1 v-for="item2 in productListAlaCarte" :key="item2">
                        <td>{{item2.prName}} {{item2.prQty}}</td>
                      </h1>
```

```
vue
 productListAlaCarte.value.push(res.data.returnData.alaCarteInfo);
          console.log(productListAlaCarte.value);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your response containing 2D array, You can iterate over it by wrap your rows in a `<template>` tag.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      productListAlaCarte: [
        [{
          prName: 'A',
          prQty: 1
        }, {
          prName: 'B',
          prQty: 1
        }],
        [{
          prName: 'C',
          prQty: 1
        }, {
          prName: 'D',
          prQty: 1
        }],
        [{
          prName: 'E',
          prQty: 2
        }, {
          prName: 'F',
          prQty: 3
        }], [], [], []]
    }
  }
});
```

```css
table, tr, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.14/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>prName</th>
      <th>prQty</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <template v-for="(data, index) in productListAlaCarte" :key="index">
        <tr v-for="(innerArrData, i) in data" :key="i">
          <td>{{ innerArrData.prName }}</td>
          <td>{{ innerArrData.prQty }}</td>
        </tr>
      </template>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank for the answer its worked, can I ask in the second v-for the 'i' is that same as 'index'?

Comment: No, both values will vary based on the iterations for each v-for loop. Outer loop will run based on the elements in the outer array and inner loop will run based on the elements in the nested arrays.